# Set chrome extension cookie value name as var

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on chrome extension and need to set a cookie:

```
chrome.cookies.set({ url: "https://www.someurl.com/", name: value });
```

This code works good but "name" should be dynamic var that ajax passed.

```
var name = response;
```

Is it posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're [using it wrong](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-set).

It should be:

```
chrome.cookies.set({
  url: "https://www.someurl.com/",
  name: someName,
  value: someValue
});
```

So you can set both as variables.

---

However, in a general case (say, `chrome.storage` API that really takes name-value maps), you could do the following:

```
var data = {};
data[name] = value; // Both are variables
chrome.storage.local.set(data);
```

When ECMAScript 6 support comes along, you'll be able to use [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_6):

```
// Does not work yet
chrome.storage.local.set({[name]: value});
```

We won't have to wait long though, [it's coming in Chrome 44](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/06/chrome-44-beta-improvements-to.html).